# Sort/reorder list by another list of the same length

Tags: r

I have two lists that I want two keep in list format.

```
list1 <- list("two", "one", "three")
list2 <- list(2, 1, 3)
```

I want to use list2 to reorder list1 while keeping both in list format. I would like the output of both lists to be as follows.

```
> list1
#[[1]]
#[1] "one"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "two"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "three"

> list2
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order` for this purpose; however, `order` expects a *vector*, so having `list2` be a list is a bit inconvenient:

```
result = list1[order(unlist(list2))]
```